# Object Apparent size and Actual Size

Tags: modeling

So I'm making an item and as illustrated below by the two black boxes there is the smaller box which is the objects apparent size and then the bigger which I want to be rendered as the actual size.

Is there a way to scale out the smaller black box to the size of the bigger black box without changing the current apparent size of the mesh?

I need to do so without adding more geometry to the mesh. I also need the objects Collision box to remain the size of the mesh so when it interacts with objects in a 3D environment it collides properly and realistically.

[image: Nail size and actual size]

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, could you clarify? Are you looking for a way to scale the objects with precision? Are you looking for camera lens effects? Do you want an illustration type zoom in? Can you please edit your question and provide some more details, possibly a reference image or animation of the desired effect?

Comment: The size of the nail when rendered depends on where it is in the camera view, you can move the camera so that the nail fills the view or change the camera focal length to zoom in on the nail. If you want to scale it in relation to other objects, then move the nail closer to the camera.